# Is it possible to generate/import an SSRS instance into a Visual Studio Project?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, bids, ssrs-2016

I have objects created in the web portal or using Report Builder. I would like everything to be source controlled in a project so I created a new project and I don't see an import wizard. I was hoping it would function the same way Analysis Services does and import all the assets from the server.

So is there a way to do this? Let's assume I have a lot of reports and datasets that I don't want to download manually.

I'm also open to a programmatic approach using C# to pull the files and add them to the project manually.

Answer (score 0):

.rdl files (basically just XML) can be added to a Visual Studio package and then managed by your chosen source control solution.

You can download the .rdl from SSRS.

I believe you have to manually create the connections and datasets.